# Calculating risk of disease

Tags: self-study, epidemiology

Suppose we are doing a cross sectional study on heart disease in males and females. If $16/10000$ males have heart disease and $10/10000$ females have heart disease, can we conclude that men have a much higher risk of heart disease than women? Why or why not?

I think you cannot since we are comparing proportions. We don't have an odds ratio.

Answer (score 4):

The odds ratio is not the only epidemiological effect measure that exists. Given you have a cross sectional study, and thus a prevalence study, the most appropriate measure is arguably the Prevalence Ratio - though for very low prevalence like the example study, Henry's approach, which is a Prevalence Odds Ratio, will work as an adequate approximation.

Prevalence in Females:  `10/10000 = 0.001` 
Prevalence in Males:  `16/10000 = 0.0016` 
Prevalence Ratio (Females as Referent Group):  `0.0016/0.001 = 1.6`

This is however a relatively imprecise ratio - the 95% CI is 0.73 to 3.52 - due to the low number of cases.

"can we conclude that men have a much higher risk of heart disease than women? Why or why not?"

Two thoughts on this:

1. What is "much higher"? On a relative scale, yes, I'd argue that having 60% more prevalent heart disease in one population is considerably higher - enough that if this was the finding of a properly conducted study with better power, I'd likely be pleased with the magnitude of the effect. But in an absolute sense? Not really - 6 more cases in 10,000 isn't much. And it's possible to have relative measures that are *massively* higher, but on an absolute scale are nearly identical for very rare diseases. Consider if your number of cases was 1 and 2. Here, the ratio is 2 (higher) but the difference in cases is now 1 case per 10,000. Herein lies the argument between risk ratios and risk differences.
2. You can't say much about the risk - which usually implies something about incidence. Prevalence is a composite measure of both Incidence and Duration of Disease. All you can say is that males have a higher *prevalence* of heart disease - they may actually get more heart disease, or they may simply have it for longer (for example, if heart disease tends to kill women swiftly).

Comment: @EpidGrad: When we do a case-control study, for example, we compute an odds ratio to measure the association between exposure and disease. The same is true for a cross-sectional study. If we are **only** given those prevalances, then can we conclude that men have a much higher risk for heart disease than women? The answer choices were: - This inference is correct - Incorrect because there is confusion between an odds ratio and a risk ratio - Incorrect because there is no comparison group - Incorrect because we are measuring proportions There is no confusion between odds ratio and a risk ratio.

Comment: @Tommyr I will leave the answer to your homework for you to choose. Your professor and I may...disagree on some things.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily turn this into an odds ratio by calculating

$$\frac{\; \frac{16}{10000-16} \;}{ \;\frac{10}{10000-10} \; }$$

and although this is not exactly $1.6$, it is close at about $1.60096$.

As to whether "men have a much higher risk of heart disease than women", I would not say so:

1. because I think it sometimes misleading to say that two very small numbers are very different (similarly I would not say that somebody with net assets worth $\$10$ was "much richer" than somebody with net assets of $\$5$); and
2. because the fact that out of $26$ people found to have heart disease $16$ were men is not significantly different from a hypothesis that half might be male, using for example the [binomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test)